# How to add 10 hrs in the Get-Date in azure cli task for Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I am using below and tried adding hrs without any luck. This returns time in UTC while I want the time in same format but 10 hrs ahead.

```
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    name: date
    displayName: dateValue
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'test'
      scriptType: 'pscore'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        $date = $(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss)
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=date]$date"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add 10 hours to the Get-Date command in Azure CLI, you can use the AddHours method.

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  name: date
  displayName: dateValue
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'test'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      $date = $(Get-Date).AddHours(10)
      $formattedDate = $date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=date]$formattedDate"
```